# Outputting the current clip filename or URL from Flowplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I am trying to get the filename or URL of the currently playing video in Flowplayer and display it in my show div. I thought I could use `getClip().completeUrl` but I get undefined as the output. If I do something that isn't a string, like getClip().fullDuration (an integer), the output works as expected. Why am I getting undefined?

Here's my javascript:

```
function getURL(){
var url = flowplayer().getClip().completeUrl;
$("#show").empty();
$('#show').append(url);
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="get" value="Get URL" onclick="getURL()" />
<input type="text" id="show" name="show" />
```

Here's the player javascript:

```
$f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.11.swf", {
buffering : false,
clip: {
        provider: 'rtmp',
        baseUrl: 'http://example.com',

        streams: [

        { url: 'flv:video123'},

        ]
    },
    plugins: {
        rtmp: {
                url: "flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.10.swf",
                netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://example.com/vod'
        }
    }
```

});

Comment: Works for me, when using the basic demo code for the Flowplayer instance. `completeUrl` is set as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/MY5sf/ I modified the output, though, as the value attribute does not make much sense on a `div`.

Comment: `console.log(flowplayer().getClip())` and use Firebug or some other Javascript development tool to view the console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the [Flowplayer documentation says](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/clip.html) about `completeUrl`:

> This is the concatenation of the clip's baseUrl property and the clip's url property. baseUrl is undefined if you did not set it explicitly.

If you have not set `baseUrl`, this could possibly mean that `completeUrl` cannot be built. But in this case it is identical to `url` anyway, so you can use that one.

```
var url = flowplayer().getClip().url;
```

#### Update

As the OP found out, apparently there is no `completeUrl` when using a RTMP stream list. But it works when using RTMP without a stream list.

Answer (score 0):

Try text box or label instead of div tag.because normally div tag don't have value attribute. Then Try

`onclick="return getURL();"` instead of  `onclick="getURL()"`.
Have u tried var `url = flowplayer().getClip(0).url;`

Comment: Have you check with combining both my and pixelistik answers.

Comment: i think we need to look at full code since it should set url before using it.